# How get pointer of struct's member from interface{}

Tags: pointers, reflection, go

I want to pass struct's pointer to function that expect interface{}. Then get (through reflection) the pointer to the struct's member and then modify it using this pointer. I've read a much of Q&A and tried much of variations, but still I can get it work.

Let's consider example below:

```
type Robot struct {
    Id int
}
f := func(i interface {}) {
    v :=  reflect.ValueOf(i).Elem().FieldByName("Id")
    ptr := v.Addr().Pointer()
    *ptr = 100
    //^ it needs to me for functions expecting the pointer: Scan(&pointerToValue)
}

robot := &Robot{}
f(robot)
println(robot.Id) //I want to get here 100
```

I think the problem in poor understanding what actually do **Addr()** and **Pointer()** methods of reflect package..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a working version of function f:

```
func f(i interface{}) {
  v := reflect.ValueOf(i).Elem().FieldByName("Id")
  ptr := v.Addr().Interface().(*int)
  *ptr = 100
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/E-y3rI8dU-)

The conversion to integer pointer goes as follows:

- `v` is a `reflect.Value` representing the `int` field.
- `v.Addr()` is a `relfect.Value` representing a pointer to the `int` field.
- `v.Addr().Interface()` is an `interface{}` containing the `int` pointer.
- `v.Addr().Interface().(*int)` [type asserts](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) the `interface{}` to a `*int`

You can set the field directly without getting a pointer:

```
func f(i interface{}) {
  v := reflect.ValueOf(i).Elem().FieldByName("Id")
  v.SetInt(100)
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/7d7GRdtqEB)

If you are passing the value along to something expecting interface{} (like the db/sql [Scan](http://godoc.org/database/sql#Row.Scan) methods), then you can remove the type assertion:

```
func f(i interface{}) {
  v := reflect.ValueOf(i).Elem().FieldByName("Id")
  scan(v.Addr().Interface())
}
```

[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/_tJyXK6jcV)

Comment: Big thank you. My brain is overloaded, I try to check it tomorrow! I think I need a time and practice to really understand what's going on here. Especially here! `v.Addr().Interface().(*int)`. Could you share where can I grasp this kind of knowledge?)

Comment: v.Addr().Interface() works great for DB actions. Thank you very much for this!

Comment: Doesn't work if the field has a type of some interface.